# htaccess doesn't rewrite all the rules

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

As i'm really new to .htaccess, i'm trying to take it easy on how much i use it. I'm rewriting some urls though the problem is, if i rewrite 3 urls, the top one is the only one working.

`RewriteEngine On`

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&sectionid=$2 [L]
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/topic/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&topic=$2 [L]

ErrorDocument 400   /error.php
ErrorDocument 401   /error.php
ErrorDocument 403   /error.php
ErrorDocument 404   /error.php
ErrorDocument 500   /error.php
```

So, if i add a new rule above the first one, that will be the only one working.
Am i using this the wrong way?

Also, how does RewriteCond work?

Comment: What is the URL that is not working for you?

Answer (score 0):

Try removing `[L]` flag or create separate RewriteCond for each rule,

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&sectionid=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/topic/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&topic=$2 [L]
```

use `[L]` on last rule.

Comment: Hi. This did not work. I rewrote it like this `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&tlocate=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&sectionid=$2

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/topic/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&topic=$2 [L]`

Comment: you have contradiction in your rule you applied `RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/$` using this condition for two different parameter `tlocate` and `sectionid` cannot be applied for same rule you have to create new rule which differentiate this condition for ex. `RewriteRule ^forums/([^/]*)/sectionid/([^/]*)/$ /forums.php?page=$1&sectionid=$2` something like this. please mention if okay with this.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Abhishek 's answer, i got it solved.

I had to use different Rewriterules for each url. So that they were unique in a way.